# holoviz/holoviews/panel: default setting of axes limits of a holomap "layouted" in separate panes

Tags: python, holoviews, holoviz, pyviz, panel-pyviz

I would like to know what would be the best way to have elements that are part of the same holomap layout but on separate panel `pane`s have their axes limits computed the same way like when the entire layout is rendered.

It is simpler with the following example.

Let's say I define a `HoloMap` that I render as a `NdLayout` of barplots:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'level_1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'level_2': ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D'],
        'group' : ['group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2'],
        'values': [3, 1, 9, 11, 5, 6, 1, 3],
    }
)
hv_ds = hv.Dataset(
    df, 
    kdims=['level_1', 'level_2', 'group'],
    vdims='values',
)
layout = hv_ds.to(
    hv.Bars,
    kdims=['level_1', 'level_2'],
    vdims='values',
).layout('group')
layout
```

This layout is cleanly rendered, with y axes limits set as to show the top of the bars:

[image: Layout]

However, if I want for customization sake to separate the elements of the layout in different panel `pane`s, the y limits are computed on the first rendered element:

```py
pn.Row(
    pn.Column(
        pn.pane.Markdown("## Group 1"),
        layout['group1'],
    ),
    pn.Column(
        pn.pane.Markdown("## Group 2"),
        layout['group2'],
    )
)
```

[image: Truncated barplot]

Is there any way to force computation of the y axes limits as when the whole layout is rendered?

As a side note, I noticed that if I render the full layout AND THEN parts of it, the axes limits are correctly set. May be this could be leveraged, but I don't know how to render a layout and then hide it...

```py
pn.Column(
    layout,
    pn.Row(
        pn.Column(
            pn.pane.Markdown("## Group 1"),
            layout['group1'],
        ),
        pn.Column(
            pn.pane.Markdown("## Group 2"),
            layout['group2'],
        )
    ),
)
```

[image: Both layout and panel row]

Comment: Great question again. When I run your code, I don't have this issue, but when I do a selection inside the graph and then reset to defaults, I do get stuck with the wrong axes just like you. Maybe it's a bug?! You could also try and post this on discourse.holoviz.org. where the developers of these packages answer questions. You can also try and install latest versions first with pip install git+https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot.git and pip install git+https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews.git

Comment: Thanks Sander. I unfortunately cannot "pip install" as the machine I am working on is shared and managed with conda. I nevertheless will upgrade my packages through conda. I posted on discourse.holoviz, however I don't know if posting the stackoverflow link is compliant with the etiquette out there... I'll keep you posted of whether the upgrade has fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, you can also do: conda install -c pyviz/label/dev holoviews

Comment: I could not manage to install the very latest version of holoviews with conda. I think I will try and adjust the plots width through hooks, if that is possible. Thanks again Sander.

Comment: pip install should normally work fine even if you're using conda, though you may want to do `conda remove -f <pkg>` to be sure you're using the pip version.